# MSIX install fails - C1570108 Msg:[Policy check failed]

Tags: powershell, msix, dism

We have an MSIX installer that we use for installing applications that we have developed. We have a customer that is trying to roll out the applications across their computers.

When they run the MSIX by double clicking it, everything works and it installs correctly. It also works when running the Powershell command:

```
Add-AppxPackage "C:\localdata\package.msix"
```

However, this only installs for the current user and they need the applications installed for all users. They are therefore using Powershell to install the MSIX for all users on the computer using the command:

```
Add-AppxProvisionedPackage -Online -PackagePath "C:\localdata\package.msix" -SkipLicense
```

This command fails with the message "The package does not meet the requirement for provisioning to the target image". When looking at the log file, it produces the errors below:

> Error                 DISM   DISM Appx Provider: PID=4668 TID=16512 onecore\admin\appmodel\utilities\provisionhelper\msixpackageadapter.cpp(629)\AppxProvider.dll!00007FFC8C374ED3: (caller: 00007FFC8C3745C3) ReturnHr(1) tid(4080) C1570108     Msg:[Policy check failed]
> CAppxManager::ResultLoggingCallback
> Error                 DISM   DISM Appx Provider: PID=4668 TID=16512 onecore\admin\appmodel\utilities\provisionhelper\msixpackageadapter.cpp(348)\AppxProvider.dll!00007FFC8C37468E: (caller: 00007FFC8C36F159) ReturnHr(2) tid(4080) C1570108     Msg:[Pre-install policy check failed for package 'TotalControlSimulator_1.2.0.1045_x64__0mjrefxxwjek0'.]
> CAppxManager::ResultLoggingCallback

The error appears to be related to a policy check, but there are no details on what policy might be failing or why. Searching for the error code (C1570108) didn't provide anything useful.

How do I troubleshoot this or get more information on what policy check is failing?

Comment: The xml file may be missing.  See FSLogix App Masking on following : https://james-rankin.com/articles/creating-converting-and-deploying-msix-packages-with-appventix/?force_isolation=true

Comment: I believe this might be an issue with AllowAllTrustedApps registry key. That must be enabled to allow sideloading of apps (not installing from the microsoft store). That key is located KEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Appx\AllowAllTrustedApps and needs to equal 1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/sideload-apps-with-dism-s14?view=windows-11#addapps

Comment: You could also try using the cmd version of the command and see if anything changes. DISM /Online /Add-ProvisionedAppxPackage /PackagePath:C:\App1.appx /SkipLicense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The customer had an incorrect setup in their registry. They had

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Appx\AllowAllTrustedApps
```

set incorrectly. When they changed this to being a Dword and setting the value to 1 it worked as expected.